# How to notify controller that download finished?

Tags: iphone

I have a class that downloads an image with NSURLConnection. I'm new to ios so i was wondering how I can "notify" my ViewController that download has finished ? What "tool's" should I use ?

Clarification:

I have implemented all the callbacks of NsUrlConnection, my problem is how to notify ViewController, from my connectionDidFinishLoading that download has finished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[my modified download bar solution](http://www.developers-life.com/progress-bar-download-file-on-iphone.html)

Comment: Found my solution there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) in which you use blocks to handle the connection response either succes or failure. It also has a nice wrapper for retrieving images and load then in a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

To use NSURLConnection you have to implement a delegate that has methods that will be called when something interesting happens with the connection. That's how you receive information on whether the connection was established, how you receive data, and also how you'll know that the connection has finished (**connectionDidFinishLoading**). More info in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE

So basically code that you put in your **connectionDidFinishLoading** has to send some kind of a message to the view controller so that it updates the view.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough I have implemented connectionDidFinishLoading, and tried NSnotificayion to send notification to controller but sent from ConnectionDidFinishLoading doesn't get received in controller, probably due to it's running in diffrent thread ? What else i can use ?

Comment: Are you using threads just for the download? It'd be easier to use the asynchronous API. that way you could send the message with a normal method call, like `[controller imageDownloaded]`.

Answer (score 0):

you should just use these methods in the class that start the nsurl-connection:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Download support (NSURLConnectionDelegate)

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.activeDownload appendData:data];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error // Never called (deprecated method not used with IOS version >> 4.3 ???)
{
    // Clear the activeDownload property to allow later attempts
    self.activeDownload = nil;

    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:self.activeDownload];

    self.activeDownload = nil;
    // Release the connection now that it's finished
    self.imageConnection = nil;
}
```

where imageConnection is a property of type NSURLConnection:

```
NSURLConnection *imageConnection
```

and activeDownload is a NSMutableData:

```
NSMutableData *activeDownload
```